# Make own View or use xml by Eclipse?

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, view, sprite

Hay guys this is only a pretty simple question.

I am new with all this android programming and in lots of tutorials everything is made with Canvas, SurvafeView etc. everyone is creating own View Class for the app layout.

For me it was pretty easy to handle some basic stuff with the xml created by Eclipse but i can find no tutorial to achieve what I want with the xml and not the View Class.

Is it smarter to create an own Class for the view or can you do everything with the xml?
I wanted to make a moving Sprite with a Bitmap but I can't find any tutorials for it.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help you: http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/the-abcs-of-android-game-development-animate-sprites/?s_cid=e066&tag=nl.e066&ttag=e066

From the ordinary you should do as much in XML as possible. Mostly you can do everything in XML and even less in code (cause XML sometimes provides additional attributes).

When it comes to animations and stuff, using code is necessary, but inflating the biggest part out of xml is still the way to go!

Comment: Thank you for the links I will see if they are helpfull. You said "the biggest part out of xml is stil the way to go" do you mean with this that you can do both? Having xml and a GameView?

Comment: Yeah you can have, but you should do as much as possible in xml to avoid missbehaviour.

Comment: Is it possible to make Animated Bitmap sprites with the xml or would I need to make a View class for that? And how can I use xml and a View class? As far as i know i can't setContentView to two different things.

Comment: You can't do everything in XML, but what you can do in XML should not be done in code. Except von "setContentView" there is the option to use a layoutInflater and stuff like that, wich doesn't need a whole layout but more some view. Just try the linked example, google for layoutInflater and try to understand the possibilities android does give you ;)

Comment: I have a question to the sprite-animation-with-android tutorial. I did everything and got no errors but if I start the app with the update part it crashes, if I take it out the app starts, but there is no picture. You have any Idea what anyone could do wrong with this tutorial? Can I just put it all next to my usual Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything is possible with xml. When we need to do things dynamically then we go from creating layouts programatically ..